# App crashes without catching any exception

Tags: java, android, json

So i'm into a tutorial at Udemy "The Complete Android N Developer Course" and trying to make lecture 86 about a weather app.

I use the API from here https://openweathermap.org/current#cityid and use JSON to get the data needed.

The app is working properly when i input a correct city name, but when the input is wrong or empty the app crashes without catching any exceptions.

I don't know why it is crashing and where to look. So i give you all the code i wrote. I tried to implement if statements here and there to try and find it but without any luck.

I would like to know where the problem is and how to fix it so the app doesn't crash anymore.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;
    String city = "";
    TextView textView;

    public void getWeather (View view)  {
        try {
            city = URLEncoder.encode(editText.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");

            if (editText.getText().toString() == "") {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textView.setText("Please enter a city.");
            } else  {
                DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
                task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&appid=c6ef169a79d84674ef7e1414301eb5c4");
            }

            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "UnsupportedEncodingException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "General exception (getWeather)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = null;
                in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "IOException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "General exception (doInBackground)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {
                String message = "";
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)    {

                    JSONObject jsonPart = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String main = "";
                    String description = "";

                    main = jsonPart.getString("main");
                    description = jsonPart.getString("description");

                    if (main != "" && description != "")    {
                        message += main + ": " + description + "\r\n";
                    }
                }

                if (message != "") {
                    textView.setText(message);
                } else  {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "JSONException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "General exception (onPostExecute)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you take the try catch block out?

Comment: you still can check the error in Android Studio even though you are using phone instead of emulator.

Comment: It requires the try and catch blocks or the app doesn't run at all. I'll look into android studio for errors, thanks John Joe.

Comment: check the error and post here

Comment: Guess you have an exception in the asynctask running on worker thread, and trying to display a toast on a non-UI thread crashes the app. Remove the try-catch to crash the app with the root cause issue and fix that.

Comment: it must be cause of changing UI from background thread.. remove toast from doinBackground().. if you really want to display that toast run in using new Runnable..

Comment: Indeed the problem was Toast in 'doInBackground'. I replaced it with 'e.printStackTrace();'. Now i understand and everything works as expected. Thanks a lot everyone :D

Comment: You should check the logcat. It's always say you what crash the application. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you're trying to changes UI with background thread inside the [doInBackground(Params...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) method of [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) with this line:

```
try {
     ...
    return result;
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (IOException e2) {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "IOException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "General exception (doInBackground)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You should not call Toast inside the [doInBackground(Params...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)). Do that inside the [onPostExecute(Result)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)).

You can avoid that by either ignoring the error or returning specific text in doInBackground. Something like this:

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        ...

        try {
            ...
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            result= "MalformedURLException";
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            result= "IOException";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do nothing and returning empty
            result= "Exception";
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // check if there is an error
        String errorMessage = "";
        switch(result) {
          case "MalformedURLException":
            errorMessage = "MalformedURLException";
            break;
          case ""IOException":
            errorMessage = "IOException";
            break;
          case "Exception":
            errorMessage = "Exception";
            break;
        }

         // there is an error, show a message.
        if(!errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Could not find weather: " + errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return; // stop the process.
        }

         // do something when no error found.

    }
}
```